# Vertical scrollbar visibility

Tags: css, sass, flexbox

There are both horizontal and vertical scroll on table body. 
As there are more number of columns, extra columns are visible by horizontal scroll due to this vertical scroll also overflowed.

I have to position the scrollbar to the right visible part always.

I tried wrapping the table inside a div and setting the width 100vw but it did not work. I also tried separately wrapping both body and header but in that case table lost its property and extra independent horizontal scroll introduced for header and body.

Is there any way i can position just scrollbar to the right most visible part of table body.

Comment: what you have done so far? please provide

Comment: I have tried grabbing the ::-webkit-scrollbar  and setting the position absolute so that i can move it right or left according to parent relative div but position property is not working on webkit-scrollbar. Then i tried wrapping the table inside a div with css width 100vw i also tried to wrap the table header and body inside a div in this case vertical scrollbar positioned but extra scroll appeared for body and header.

Comment: if i add

 tbody {
overflow: initial !important; }

header is also scrolled.

Comment: What do you mean by - extra columns are visible by horizontal scroll due to this vertical scroll also overflowed.

Comment: When table has a horizontal scroll, the vertical scrollbar is visible only AFTER we scroll horizontally to the end.